# Is there any algorithmic-pseudocode/Python-implementation for the DAG-related API(s) in the R package dagitty?

Tags: r, python, references, causality, dag

The statistical software [DAGgity](https://journals.lww.com/epidem/fulltext/2011/09000/DAGitty__A_Graphical_Tool_for_Analyzing_Causal.22.aspx?casa_token=PaR-RH5ZphIAAAAA:aJMZFBC8K_iUzSbQ5bLVv471WY76hhPxJR_Xujzdu3V8L_S7ozuPsElIV5-gb4DGH3ILi7TQIh__K5m11tr4_9Un) offers a [graphical web-based UI](https://www.dagitty.net/) as well as an [implementation in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dagitty/dagitty.pdf) that allows for finding conditional independences corresponding to d-separation, minimal adjustment sets for causal effect, and much more. The rapid response of the UI indicates that the implementations are efficient.

Since I am looking to work in Python, I would be grateful for any references regarding either of the below

- Algorithmic pseudocode corresponding to the API(s)
- A Python implementation of DAGgity (or parts of it)
- Any Python libraries with similar functionality

(The graphical UI is not relevant for my task - I merely need the functionality.)

> **Disclaimer**: For everyone with an urge to close this or move it to stackoverflow: The question asks for statistical software with specific properties and capabilities, *not* programming, routine operations, or datasets. It *even allows for* algorithmic-pseudocode, often available in textbooks, papers etc.

Comment: I don't see why this question would be closed - it asks for a statistical software reference. It does not concern programming, debugging, routine tasks, or datasets. If statistical software is not a statistical topic, I do wonder what the ASA Journal of Statistical Software is all about.

Comment: I'm not sure what "much more" refers to. What about [DoWhy](https://github.com/py-why/dowhy)? > DoWhy is a Python library for causal inference that supports explicit modeling and testing of causal assumptions. DoWhy is based on a unified language for causal inference, combining causal graphical models and potential outcomes frameworks.

Comment: @dipetkov I had checked [DoWhy](https://github.com/py-why/dowhy) earlier. It's graphical causal module is experimental and not as developed as `dagitty`. As for what "much more" might indicate, [this] (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dagitty/dagitty.pdf) doc shows the rich array of function API(s) `dagitty` has, many of which I think are not present in DoWhy. Example - a function to list down all the minimal d-separators in a DAG i.e., the testable implications in DAGitty. Besides, and I am not sure about this, response time of DAGitty seems lower.

Comment: Re the disclaimer: unfortunately, it has long been the practice of this community to consider requests for software off topic.  To help you, we maintain a list of resources you can consult: see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software.

Comment: There is also the generic option to call R from python: https://rpy2.github.io.

Comment: @whuber one of my main points in adding the edit was to convey the idea that, any resources like paper/textbook etc., which describe the algorithms in detail are welcome. Request for Python-based implementation was a bonus, in the sense that I am familiar with it. However, if it ultimately resembles a software-related request, then no issues. Anyways I think @dipetkov 's reference to `rpy2` might solve the issue; of course not in a way I might have imagined when I put this query.